# Speech Marks Razor MVC

Tags: c#, razor, model-view-controller

```
@if (Model.HasAccount) { @Model.AccountName } else {<span class="label label-danger">ACCOUNT MISSING</span>}
```

How do I add speech marks (") around the @Model.AccountName?

EDIT: I want to display @Model.AccountName with speech marks around it. I can't seem to get it working with @:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
@if (Model.HasAccount) { @Html.Raw("\"" + @Model.AccountName + "\""); } else {<span class="label label-danger">ACCOUNT MISSING</span>}
```

Comment: I need it to display speech marks, not brackets, around the account name.

Comment: @Html.Raw('"' + @Model.AccountName + '"')

This worked. Thanks. I used single quotes.